# All Possible Groupings in a Matrix Chain Application

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have studied matrix chain multiplication, wherein given a sequence of matrices, the goal is to find the most efficient way to multiply matrices. The problem is not actually to perform the multiplications, but merely to decide the sequence of the matrix multiplications involved.

So say for example. Given 2 matrices A and B, I can have one possible matrix combination which is `(AB)` and when my matrices are 3: `A, B, C,` I can have two possible combinations: `(AB)C` and `A (BC)`. I want to implement a code given the number of matrices will output all possible matrix combinations in Python.

The code below is not right because given n = 3 matrices it outputs 5 combinations, when in fact it should be 2 only. The code below is printing all combinations of balanced parentheses.

```
 def printParenthesis(str, n): 
     if(n > 0): 
         _printParenthesis(str, 0,  
                      n, 0, 0,0); 
     return; 

 def _printParenthesis(str, pos, n,  
                  open, close, count): 

     if(close == n): 
         for i in str: 
             print(i, end = ""); 
         print(); 
         return; 
     else: 
         if(open > close): 
             str[pos] = '}'; 
             _printParenthesis(str, pos + 1, n,  
                          open, close + 1, count); 
         if(open < n): 
             str[pos] = '{' + chr(65+count); 
            _printParenthesis(str, pos + 1, n,  
                          open + 1, close, count+1); 

# Driver Code 
n = 3;  //Number of matrices
str = [""] * 2 * n; 
printParenthesis(str, n);
```

How will I modify my code above to fit my problem? Please help .

Answer (score 1):

See below link , I cannot comment on this low points, so pls bear
https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/matrix-chain-multiplication-dp-8/amp/

Comment: Thanks, but I think its not what Im looking for.

Comment: I want to print all possible combinations of matrices that can be tried in matrix chain application